# How to Edit text file in .exe.config file in vb net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have vb .net project that use config file to setting the connection. Existing i have to open config file to change the value of app setting in that file, but i think it's not user friendly, so i want to change the value at .exe.config file using form, do anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write to the main exe's .config userSettings section?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629143/how-to-write-to-the-main-exes-config-usersettings-section)

Comment: nope, i talk about vb.net, but thank you ..

Comment: Same thing - it's all .NET.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18270420/62576

Comment: The question linked to by Ken White loads the config file as a standard XML document but, given that the .NET Framework includes types specifically designed to work with config files, you should use that specialised functionality instead.  Here's an example: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?532768-NET-2-0-Protected-Configuration-(Encrypting-Config-Files)&highlight=

Comment: I use the source code in vb forum via url given by Ken White, it works, thanks ..

Comment: ups I mean url from jmcilhinney,
Hello jmcilhinney, i want to mark your answer as correct answer, please add your comment to answer column ..